# How do you convert an FString of delimited floats to a TArray<uint16> using Unreal C++

Tags: c++, unreal-engine4

Given an FString of "123.2222,446.4444,55234.2342" how do you convert this to a TArray of type uint16?

Current attempt is to parse the string into an array using

```
TArray<FString> Parsed;
    HeightMapData.ParseIntoArray(Parsed, TEXT(","), false);
```

This seems to work well. Next is the problem of how do I convert this to  uint16.

I am trying

```
const TArray<uint16*>& parsedArray = reinterpret_cast<const TArray<uint16*>&>(Parsed);
```

But it is not working.  Error: Parent address is invalid for parsedArray

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't `reinterpret_cast` and pretend your array of strings is an array of integers.  You need to convert each string to an integer in a new array:

```
TArray<uint16> intArray;
for (const auto& str : Parsed)
    intArray.Add(FCString::Atoi(str));
```

Ref: https://docs.unrealengine.com/4.26/en-US/ProgrammingAndScripting/ProgrammingWithCPP/UnrealArchitecture/StringHandling/FString/